# Spring boot embedded tomcat threadpool configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-8

Application is built using spring boot.My application uses application.yaml for external config .But when i am trying to add below config in application.yaml , application fails to start with error as tomcat is not valid.However similar equivalent config I have tried in another application with application.propeties it works there.

```
server:
    port:8080
    tomcat:
      max-threads:500
      accept-count:500
      max-connections:10000
      min-spare-threads:500
```

Comment: did you try with a application.properties file with server.tomcat.max-threads=500 ?
This could tell you if the error is in your yaml.

Comment: yes application.properties i tried with that application , it works fine but with application.yaml it says error

Comment: i don't think its indetation issue

Comment: Maybe any invisible chars in the yaml? Rewrite the yaml manuall and take care on the indents.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65897933/edit) your question and add the error log lines.

Answer (score 3):

What is the springBoot version being used in the other application ?

FYI
**server.tomcat.max-threads** is deprecated since **Springboot 2.3,** now use **server.tomcat.threads.max** in your Spring application.properties.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties

Answer (score 0):

For me this seems to work in `application.yaml`

```
server:
    port: 8080
    tomcat: 
        max-threads: 500
        accept-count: 500
        max-connections: 10000
        min-spare-threads: 500
```

or this in `application.properties`

```
server.port = 8080
server.tomcat.max-threads = 500
server.tomcat.accept-count = 500
server.tomcat.max-connections = 10000
server.tomcat.min-spare-threads = 500
```

If it doesn't work, maybe there is an error in your dependencies?